# PHP cURL filling form but not submitting data

Tags: php, html, forms, curl

I'm trying to create a simple cURL connection to fill in a POST form, but for some reason it's not.. doing what it's supposed to do?

This is my code;

HTML form

```
<html>
   <body>
      <form method="post" action="test.php">
         Name <input type="text" name="name"><br>
         Username <input type="text" name="username"><br>
         Email <input type="text" name="email"><br>
         Pass: <input type="text" name="password"><br>
         Pass2: <input type="text" name="password2"><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>
   </body>
</html>
```

PHP Form

```
<?php
   $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'hawbaw') or mysqli_error($con);
   $name = $_POST['name'];
   $username = $_POST['username'];
   $email = $_POST['email'];
   $pass = $_POST['password'];
   $pass2 = $_POST['password2'];
   mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO haw (`id`, `name`, `username`, `password`, `email`) VALUES (NULL, '$name', '$username', '$pass', '$email')");
   ?>
```

cURL Connection

```
<?php
   $data = array();
   $data['name'] = '123';
   $data['username'] = '123';
   $data['email'] = '123';
   $data['password'] = '123';
   $data['password2'] = '123';
   $data['submit'] = 'Submit';

   $post_str = '';

   foreach ($data as $key=>$value) {
       $post_str.= $key . '=' . urlencode($value) . '&';
   }

   $post_str = substr($post_str, 0, -1);

   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost/test.html');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_str);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

   $response = curl_exec($ch);
   ?>
```

The cURL data

```
curl 'http://localhost/test.php' -H 'Origin: http://localhost' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/52.0.2743.82 Safari/537.36' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Referer: http://localhost/test.html' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' --data 'name=21312&username=21321&email=21312&password=21321&password2=12321&submit=Submit' --compressed
```

Comment: Do you have any errors, output ? anythings ?

Comment: @Nicolas When I echo the `$response` I just get the blank HTML form loaded to me

Comment: It's been a while since I used cURL, but If I'm reading this correctly, you're posting to an HTML file.

Comment: @alanlittle Yes, and that HTML form is connected to a PHP file that submits to a database. Nothing is being inserted into the database though (it is when manually filling the HTML form, not through the cURL request).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you should call directly your PHP file. The HTML page has no way to get the POST parameters and insert it by itself into the form.

Comment: @Nicolas Yes, directly calling to the PHP file would make it work. But is there no way to make it submit an actual HTML form just like it would manually? Basically by submitting the "submit" button and going to the action of the form.

Comment: Well no since there is no point. Both action goes to the same place. Why not simply call your PHP file ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "connected to" a PHP file. HTML is not a scripting language, and has no way of handling the POST data. You need to POST to a PHP script, which then outputs the HTML.